# questão 23 project euler

Tags: python

'''Um número perfeito é um número para o qual a soma de seus divisores apropriados é exatamente igual ao número. Por exemplo, a soma dos divisores apropriados de 28 seria 1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14 = 28, o que significa que 28 é um número perfeito.

Um número n é chamado de deficiente se a soma de seus divisores próprios for menor que n e for chamada abundante se essa soma exceder n.

Como 12 é o menor número abundante, 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 = 16, o menor número que pode ser escrito como a soma de dois números abundantes é 24. Por análise matemática, pode ser mostrado que todos os inteiros maiores que 28123 pode ser escrito como a soma de dois números abundantes. No entanto, esse limite superior não pode ser reduzido por análise, embora se saiba que o maior número que não pode ser expresso como a soma de dois números abundantes é menor que esse limite.

Encontre a soma de todos os inteiros positivos que não podem ser escritos como a soma de dois números abundantes.'''

## Python 3

```
#função verifica se o número é abundante
def AbundantNumber(x):
    div = 0
    for i in range(1, int(x/2 + 1)):
        if x%i == 0:
           div = div + i
        if div > x:
            return 1

#criação de uma lista com os números abundantes até 28123
NumAb = []
for i in range(1, 28123):
    if AbundantNumber(i) == 1:
        NumAb = NumAb + [i]

#Soma 2 a 2 dos termos da lista no par´´agrafo anterior
SomAb = []
    for a in range(0, len(NumAb)):
        for b in range(a, len(NumAb)):
            if NumAb[a] + NumAb[b] < 28123:
                SomAb = SomAb + [NumAb[a]+NumAb[b]]
            else:
                break
    print(SomAb)
```

Comment: desculpe, sou novo aqui, esqueci de fazer a pergunta. Como posso melhorar esse código para que fique viável a execução?

Comment: Faltou fazer a pergunta, mostrar o código feito e apontar onde exatamente tem dúvida, aqui não é um site de "faz pra mim"

Comment: eu sei cara, desculpa aí, sou novo aqui e essa foi minha primeira pergunta no site. Eu mostrei o código feito porém apesar de ter convicção da certeza sei q está muito mau otimizado. Gostaria de saber onde o q posso fazer no meu código para que seja processado de forma mais rápida. Obrigado pela resposta

Comment: Em Python a indentação é fundamental. Indente corretamente seu código para tentarmos entende-lo. Veja a ajuda para formatação.